# npm install throwing errors related to typescript

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I am trying to build and use the open-source [Tornado-cash cli](https://github.com/tornadocash/tornado-cli)

I am using nodejs version 18.6.0, npm version 8.13.2 and Ubuntu 20.04 (focal)

However, when i run the **npm-install** in the project directory i get the following error;

[image]

I am having great trouble resolving this error, i have searched extensively ( on this site & others ) but i have not been able to solve this

It seems that the problem is related to typescript syntax

I am not very proficient in JavaScript. I figure that anyone who has good proficiency in js will be able to resolve this

I would be grateful for any help !

Answer (score -1):

I guess the problem is in the permissions. İt can be solved if you type sudo before npm-install

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).